# Can't format my numbers to 3 decimal points (.000)

Tags: java, swing, decimalformat

```
public class SimpleTrig {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DecimalFormat dx;
        dx = new DecimalFormat("0.000");

        String angleStr;
        double angle, angleCosine;

        angleStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter an angle (in degrees)");
        angle = Double.parseDouble(angleStr);
        angleCosine = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The cosine of " + angle 
                                      + " degrees is " + dx.format(angleCosine));
    }
}
```

The output of angleCosine is giving me an output of 0.000 as my final answer regardless of any angle I input.

Comment: I just ran the entire thing and I don't get 0.000 as a result, I get various different results depending on the input.

Comment: what angle are you trying? i tried your code with 60degrees and i got 0.500 as output

Answer (score 0):

Use `new DecimalFormat("#.###")`

Comment: consider accepting an answer by clicking the "tick" beside your preferred answer

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 dx = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
```

into

```
 dx = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
```

Or

```
 dx = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat( "#0.00" );
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the format to

```
DecimalFormat dx = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine when I run it, enter 45, get 0.707. using java 1.6.0_30

Had to add final closing bracket and package definition to get it to run.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
  DecimalFormat dx = new DecimalFormat("##,##0.000");
```

or Check angleCosine value is proper.